# Change meta description/keywords dynamically with php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, meta-tags, meta

Im trying to grab some info from the db and use it as meta desc and keyword. But something isnt working as it supposed to.

EDIT: after alot of help i got it semi working. If there is no blogID i want it to fallback on the other part... that part of the script aint working, any ideas?

```
<?php
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=blog";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, "**********", "********");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$id = $_GET['postID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blogID=:id ORDER BY blogID DESC";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute (array($id));
                    while($metta = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) )

if (isset($metta['blogID']) && !empty($metta['blogID'])) { 
$keywords = $metta['keywords']; 
$description = $metta['description']; 
} else { 
$keywords = "blalbalbalblabla"; 
$description = "blabla"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: You're calling $meta, but in the code you've shown $meta hasn't been defined.

Comment: @awl19 yea, that part got lost when i copy pasted it ^^ edited my post

Comment: What's the output you get from $meta[2]?

Comment: @awl19 feels like i have a mess in my head atm the meta desc and key should be <?php echo '$keyword';?> and ditto but $description instead. however that does not seem to be the problem. $meta[2] is the blog_post column of the table

Comment: Ha, I get that. But the thing is, from what I can see...$keywords (note the s on the end, there) and $description are being called from $row. What is $row? I don't see it defined. You say $meta[2] is the blog_post column in your table, but what is it actually spitting out? Is it blank, is it giving an error, is it giving the value? What?

Comment: @awl19 updated my post

Comment: @awl19 with that code i get the right values for atleast keywords. description is blank, guess its because i want to use the same info twice. however it is working now. Is there anyway to just grab the text, not <img> etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116721/discussion-between-awl19-and-per-kallstrom).

Comment: @awl19 heelp pleeease ;)

Comment: Haha, what's up? I sent you a PM

Comment: @awl19 I SOLVED IT!!! btw write on fb if u want webspace :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the prettiest code... but it works!

```
<?php
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=blog";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, "*****", "*******");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$id = $_GET['postID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE blogID=:id";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute (array($id));
                    $metta = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

if (isset($_GET['postID'])) { 
$keywords = $metta['keywords']; 
$description = $metta['description']; 

}
sqlsrv_close($con);
?>


<meta name="description" content="<?= isset($description) ? $description : 'blablabla'; ?>">
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?= isset($keywords) ? $keywords : 'blablabla'; ?>">
```

Comment: You better get rid of the while loop

Comment: how should it be then? im not the best at this haha

Comment: Just fetch. Without loop. You may want to check the example in the manual